# Error en stack al pedir un string

Tags: c

Mi intención con este pequeño código es pedir una cadena de tamaño máximo `MAX_CADENA`. En el caso de que sea mas grande, se volverá a pedir. Para ello he creado estas dos funciones. En la primera calcula la longitud de la cadena, que funciona perfectamente.

```
int lonCadena(char cad[]){
    int len;
    len = 0;
    
    while(cad[len] != '\0'){
        len++;
    }
    printf("Len: %d\n", len);
    
    return len;
}
```

La segunda función es la que pide la cadena en sí. El problema esta cuando introduzco varias veces la cadena porque al principio tiene un tamaño superior. Cuando introduzco la ultima de tamaño correcto, el programa se rompe.

```
char pedirCadena(){
    char cad[MAX_CADENA];
    
    do{
        printf("cadena: ");
        scanf("%s", cad);
    }while(lonCadena(cad) > MAX_CADENA);
    
    return *cad;
}
```

Comment: Leer la entrada del usuario con `scanf` te va a llevar a errores, muy serios, y dolores de cabeza. En este caso, si es mas larga la cadena de lo que deveria, ya es muy tarde, ya sobrepasaste el buffer. Te recomiendo lo que me recomendaron a mi, y me resolvio los problemas. Para la entrada del usuario, busca: `fgets` y `sscanf`. Ya con esas 2 funciones y un poco de coco vas a resolver tus problemas.

Comment: no puedo usar esas dos funciones, tiene que ser de otra manera

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer entonces es tener un buffer mas grande para la primera lectura, y si no se pasa del tamaño puedes copiarlo.